# How to switch between 2 data sources for ListBox.ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, binding, itemscontrol, multibinding

What is the **best/elegant** way to bind  ItemsControl.ItemsSource to **2** different sources best on a given property?

The binding should be done only to one of the 2 collection, the selection to which collection the ItemsControl is bound to should be based on some property.

I have a View which is bound to a ViewModel.
The collections which I want to bind to are located in different hierarchy path under that ViewModel.

I've a solution which is based on MultiBinding but I think there should be more elegant solution.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="CVS">
      <CollectionViewSource.Source  >
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myMultiBindingConverter}">
              <Binding  Path="XXXX.YYYY.ObservableCollection1"  />
              <Binding Path="XXXX.ObservableCollection2" />                    
          </MultiBinding>
      </CollectionViewSource.Source>                            
</CollectionViewSource>

<ListBox  x:Name="myListBox"                                   
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CVS}}" />
```

the Converter:

```
public class myMultiBindingConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            if(myDependecyProperty == getFirstCollection)
            {
              //make sure the item is of first collection type based on its item property
              return item;
             }
            else
            {
              //make sure the item is of the second collection type
              return item;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not have the `ViewModel` contain a property that combines the two collections? After all, it is supposed to model the view :)

Comment: @Rachel I would like to be bound only to one of this 2 collection base on a condition I would like to be able to choose which collection it is

Comment: In that case, a `DataTrigger` might be more appropriate here, as it will correctly re-evaluate the `ItemsSource` property when your condition changes.

Comment: @Rachel DataTrigger is the right way add it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Sure, it's been added as an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DataTrigger` would probably be more appropriate here since you want to change the `ItemsSource` binding based on another value

```
<Style x:Key="MyListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding XXX.ObservableCollection2}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeValue}" Value="SecondCollection">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding XXX.YYY.ObservableCollection2}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Unlike a Converter, a `DataTrigger` will correctly get re-evaluated whenever the triggered value changes